# Integer.parseInt(String str) java.lang.NumberFormatException: Errors

Tags: java, string, integer, numberformatexception

I keep getting number format expectations, even though I'm trimming the strings and they don't contain non numerical characters bizarrely it works for some numbers and not others. Below is an example of a string I get number format exception for. Also, any string starting with 0 e.g "0208405223", is returned 208405223, there's no zero anymore is that supposed to happen?

```
String n="3020857508";
Integer a = Integer.parseInt(n.trim());
System.out.println(a);
```

This is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3020857508"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:583)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at JavaBeans.Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

Comment: Because the number goes out of range for an `int`.

Comment: The removed zero is expected; an int only has a value, not a notion of the format, and any leading zeroes would be formatting unrelated to the value. If you need to output it with leading zeroes to a specified width, you'd need to convert it back to a String using [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) with an appropriate format code, e.g. `"%010d"` to make the output ten characters wide with zero padding if the value requires less than 10 characters to display.

Comment: yes thanks, I realise my mistake now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because `3020857508` exceeds `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. You should use `long` to convert the string to number.

```
java> String n="3020857508";
//=> java.lang.String n = "3020857508"
java> Integer a = Integer.parseInt(n.trim());
//=> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3020857508"
java> Integer.MAX_VALUE
//=> java.lang.Integer res2 = 2147483647
java> Long a = Long.parseLong(n.trim());
//=>java.lang.Long a = 3020857508
```

The above is [javarepl](http://www.javarepl.com/console.html) output.

If you are using JDK9 or above, you can see the same result in jshell.

```
jshell> String n="3020857508"
n ==> "3020857508"

jshell> Integer a = Integer.parseInt(n.trim())
|  Exception java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3020857508"
|        at NumberFormatException.forInputString (NumberFormatException.java:65)
|        at Integer.parseInt (Integer.java:652)
|        at Integer.parseInt (Integer.java:770)
|        at (#2:1)

jshell> Integer.MAX_VALUE
$3 ==> 2147483647

jshell> Long a = Long.parseLong(n.trim());
a ==> 3020857508
```

Answer (score 9):

The largest number parseable as an `int` is `2147483647` (2<sup>31</sup>-1), and the largest `long` is `9223372036854775807` (2<sup>63</sup>-1), only about twice as long.

To parse arbitrarily long numbers, use:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

BigInteger number = new BigInteger(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

MAX_INT is 2147483647 and you're trying to parse a bigger number as Integer.

You can use `Long.parseLong` instead:

```
System.out.println(Long.parseLong("3020857508")); // 3020857508
```

Answer (score 0):

The number you're trying to parse is larger than the max value of an `Integer`, you would have to use a larger data type like `Long`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Integer max value: " + Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    System.out.println("Long max value: " + Long.MAX_VALUE);
    System.out.println();

    String n = "3020857508";
    Long a = Long.parseLong(n.trim());
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

Results:

```
Integer max value: 2147483647
Long max value: 9223372036854775807

3020857508
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
String n="3020857508";
Long a = Long.valueOf(n.trim()).longValue();
System.out.println(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like what @Codebender said. Your value is out of range for int. Try using long/Long instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String n="3020857508";
    Long l = Long.parseLong(n.trim());
    System.out.println(l);
```

Integer MAX_VALUE : 2147483647,
Long MAX_VALUE : 9223372036854775807

As string n will not fit in `Integer` after conversion we have to use `Long`.

And if you are still not sure about range that can come in String. go with `BigInteger`where number is held in an `int[]`

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the integer range is from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 make sure your numeric value is between the same.